# Printing secured services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

ArcGIS Server Version: 10.4.0
ArcGIS JS API: 3.25
ArcGIS Desktop: 10.2.1
Browser: IE 11

In my web application, I am consuming secured services and have a requirement to print the map contents.

Initially, the token expiry was set to default (i.e. 60 mins) and everything worked fine including printing, using the Utilities/PrintingTools GP Service.

As part of the requirement, the token expiry was increased from 60 mins to 240 mins - everything still worked fine except for printing! Looking up the esri help it was clear I had to create a custom service. I created the custom service as described in the help documents, but it still fails with the following error:

> Error executing tool. Export Web Map Task Job ID:
>   jb88972125ace4b6593c8055ee779e920 : Layer "dynLyrId": Unable to
>   connect to map server at
>   https://server.domain:6443/arcgis/rest/services/WebViewer/MapServer/.
>   Failed to execute (Export Web Map). Failed to execute (Export Web Map
>   Task).

The custom service has a user connection (with saved credentials) embedded into it as required.

Upon investigating further, I found out that if I remove the token from the WebMapAsJson, it works like a charm (in ArcCatalog at least)!

I don't know how to do that as I am not creating the WebMapAsJson manually, but the esri JS API creates it while sending the request. I also tried to increase the ArcGIS Servers' shortTimeout value from 60 to 240 but even that failed.

Any ideas to make the printing work with long-validity tokens?

Comment: This may help. Looks like if the token is generated using HTTP Referrer then it fails, but using requesting IP in the export map object it works. https://community.esri.com/thread/71088

Comment: I generate the token after the user successfully logins to the application. The token is generated using the 'RequestIP' parameter - so I don't think the HTTP referrer scenario would apply. If I remove the token then the print request goes without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after trying all possible solutions and none of them working - I had it working as follows:

- The PrintTask object was created as usual, along with other parameters
- Fetched the map as JSON using the much useful but undocumented function:
  `printTaskObj._getPrintDefinition(map, params)`
- Removed the token from the WebMapJSON
- Added *ExportOptions* to the JSON above
- Prepared the parameters manually, and called the execute REST endpoint (using standard XHR) for the GPTask. This is important as now I don't need to trigger the *.execute()* method of the task.